# Xamarin Forms Bind ImageSource to element inside element

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. I have the following List:

```
Set AlbumsForList = new Set
{
    Name = album.Name,
    Pictures = new SetPictures
    {
        Picture = new List<SetPicture>()
    },
    Price = album.Price
};

albumList.Add(AlbumsForList);
```

And the SetPicture has a element called `imageSource`, that I want to bind to an image.
Here is the XAML:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding albumList}" SelectionMode="Single"
    SelectionChanged="OnCollectionViewSelectionChanged">
    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" />
    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid HeightRequest="100" VerticalOptions="Center">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="3"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <ff:CachedImage  Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" Aspect="AspectFill" Source="{Binding DemoImage}" />

                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"  
                        HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" 
                        FontSize="18" />
                <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                    <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Pictures}" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ff:CachedImage  HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="55" Aspect="AspectFill" Source="{Binding imageSource}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ScrollView>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

And finally here are my classes:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "picture")]
public class SinglePicture
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(ElementName = "sizes")]
    public Sizes Sizes { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public ImageSource imageSource { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "pictures")]
public class SinglePictures
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "picture")]
    public List<SinglePicture> Picture { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "picture")]
public class SetPicture
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "size")]
    public string Size { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "price")]
    public string Price { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "quantity")]
    public string Quantity { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "sizes")]
    public Sizes Sizes { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public ImageSource imageSource { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "pictures")]
public class SetPictures
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "picture")]
    public List<SetPicture> Picture { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "set")]
public class Set
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "price")]
    public string Price { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "pictures")]
    public SetPictures Pictures { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public ImageSource DemoImage { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "sets")]
public class Sets
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "set")]
    public List<Set> Set { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "size")]
public class Size
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "price")]
    public string Price { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "sizes")]
public class Sizes
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "size")]
    public List<Size> Size { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "data")]
public class Data
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "sets")]
    public Sets Sets { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "pictures")]
    public SinglePictures Pictures { get; set; }
}
```

Now we are already inside the listAlbums, so I defined the `Binding Pictures`, but then in the CachedImage I need to go inside the `Picture` to get the element `imageSource`, but how can I do that?

Comment: What is the parent view of the Stacklayout? You could  provide the full code in xmal and ViewModel .

Comment: I added the full XAML to the question and I don't think the ViewModel is relevant for this question. I need to know how I can access an element from an object in an object. In my case: `albumList -> Pictures -> Picture -> imageSource`.... I already know how to get to Picture, but what then?

Comment: You could check my answer .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your page contains the bindable layout in a CollectionView.

Actually , you could use list in list as the ItemsSource of CollectionView .

#### in code behind

```
public class VM_CounterList
{
  

    public ObservableCollection<AlbumsForList> albumList { get; set; }


    public VM_CounterList()
    {
        albumList = new ObservableCollection<AlbumsForList>() {


             new AlbumsForList(){ 
             
                 Name="No.1",
                 DemoImage = "screen.png",
                 Pictures = new ObservableCollection<MyImage>{ new MyImage() {ImageSource="screen.png" },new MyImage() {ImageSource="screen.png" },new MyImage() {ImageSource="screen.png" },new MyImage() {ImageSource="screen.png" },new MyImage() {ImageSource="screen.png" },new MyImage() {ImageSource="screen.png" } },
             },

             new AlbumsForList(){

                 Name="No.1",
                 DemoImage = "screen.png",
                 Pictures = new ObservableCollection<MyImage>{ new MyImage() {ImageSource="screen.png" },new MyImage() {ImageSource="screen.png" },new MyImage() {ImageSource="screen.png" },new MyImage() {ImageSource="screen.png" },new MyImage() {ImageSource="screen.png" },new MyImage() {ImageSource="screen.png" } },
             },

             new AlbumsForList(){

                 Name="No.1",
                 DemoImage = "screen.png",
                 Pictures = new ObservableCollection<MyImage>{ new MyImage() {ImageSource="screen.png" },new MyImage() {ImageSource="screen.png" },new MyImage() {ImageSource="screen.png" },new MyImage() {ImageSource="screen.png" },new MyImage() {ImageSource="screen.png" },new MyImage() {ImageSource="screen.png" } },
             },

             new AlbumsForList(){

                 Name="No.1",
                 DemoImage = "screen.png",
                 Pictures = new ObservableCollection<MyImage>{ new MyImage() {ImageSource="screen.png" },new MyImage() {ImageSource="screen.png" },new MyImage() {ImageSource="screen.png" },new MyImage() {ImageSource="screen.png" },new MyImage() {ImageSource="screen.png" },new MyImage() {ImageSource="screen.png" } },
             },

        };


        
    }

}

public class AlbumsForList : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<MyImage> Pictures { get; set; }

    private string demoImage;
    public string DemoImage
    {
        set
        {
            if (demoImage != value)
            {
                demoImage = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("DemoImage");
            }
        }
        get { return demoImage; }
    }
}
  

public class MyImage : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    

    private string imageSource;
    public string ImageSource
    {
        set
        {
            if (imageSource != value)
            {
                imageSource = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ImageSource");
            }
        }
        get { return imageSource; }
    }
}
```

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Image  HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="55" Aspect="AspectFill" Source="{Binding ImageSource}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

So that you don't need to change the code in xaml , it works fine like the following screen shot .

I used local image just for demo .

[image]

Comment: Okay, but I don't think that will work for me. I shared my classes as well. Can you please take a look at that and then modify your code to what I want?

Comment: You could put the property `public List<SinglePicture> Picture { get; set; }` directly in `Set` . It is unwise to define such more level of model .

Comment: Okay, but how do I set it with the XML Tags in that class. Because Then I need to set the Array name of the XML: `pictures` and the Element Name: `picture` at the List<SinglePicture>. How can I do that? Because now my List with pictures is empty!

Comment: You could check my answer and just need to change the class name

Comment: Yeah, I understand that, but what you said about changing the property in my Class Set, the parsing of XML doesn't succeed, because the `List<SinglePicture> Picture` stays empty. This is because my XML has a tag `<pictures>` and then `<picture>` And I need both for the List

Comment: Could you share your sample?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207262/discussion-between-a-vreeswijk-and-lucas-zhang-msft).